# Period option in alerts section of Azure

Tags: azure, alert

I have recently started working with Windows Azure and have read that they have an option of setting up alerts. I tried to set up an alert and found that there was an option called period which is defined as *"Time span during which to monitor the metric data specified by the alert rule"*. This definition is somewhat unclear to me.

**For continuous metric like CPU** : If I select the period to be '5 min', does that mean that Azure will monitor the metric for 5 minutes and if the metric is above the threshold for the entire 5 min, only then the alert will be raised. Or does it mean that Azure will monitor the metric in a 5 min window and if the metric goes above the threshold in that window, the alert will be raised.

**For discrete metrics like Server Exceptions** : For metrics like Server Exceptions which are discrete in nature, if I set the period to be 5 min, does it mean that the metric is summed and in any 5 min window if the sum reaches above the threshold then the alert will be raised.

Can anyone please elaborate on my above understanding and confirm if I am correct/wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The period that you choose specifies the interval over which metrics are aggregated. It doesn't affect how often the alert is evaluated: that depends on the frequency of arrival of metrics.

So **for continuous metrics** in your example, the evaluation will aggregate the metric over the preceding period(if you specify 5 min, it will aggregates the metric over last 5 min) and then compares the average value to the threshold to determine the new state of the alert. And for **discrete metrics**, it will sum the values and compare the total with the threhold.

For more information, please refer to [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-alerts/).

Comment: Hi, how about custom log search? I have set up this alert rule: "Whenever count of results in Custom log search log query for last 5 minutes is greater than 0. Evaluated every 5 minutes."
I have 3 rows that are returned from my query so it is greater than 0 and the first time I put it up it worked. I would just think that I would get emails every 5 min. There is still 3 rows returned from my custom query. But it only sent 1 email. I added 1 more row, so total is now 4 and my alert rule is still valid, and this time I got an email. I am not sure how to understand timespan in custom log search.

Answer (score 1):

In case of the continuous metric - like CPU, it takes the average value over your timespan. So if you set the threshold at 40% and the period to 5 minutes, the alert will fire if the average CPU load is over 40% in the 5 minute window.

For the discrete metrics, it's indeed about totals. So if you set the threshold to 5 and period to 5 minutes, the alert will fire you have get over 5 occurrences within the window.

To get more insight into these alert rules - checking out the PowerShell interface for them: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/02/26/retrieving-resource-metrics-and-creating-alert-rules-via-azure-powershell/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt282468.aspx